# Jquery comments

Tags: jquery, comments, items

I am looking for a jquery plugin + css that would display comments in a list, and also allow basic functions such as insert, delete, update. Something maybe like current stackoverflow comment section.

Thanks

Comment: CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functions are database-related, so I think we'd need to know your database and server-side language configuration.

Comment: Javascript/jQuery are client-side languages meaning they can not store data in a database (other than maybe cookies or html5 localstorage) without a server-side backend (php, ruby, etc.).

Comment: It looks like John is looking to handle "list CRUD" using similar patterns as with DBs, but not necessarily for database use -- for similar reasons why we may use LINQ to Objects in .NET, for using query logic.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am actually looking for a jquery+css solution for this control. I am planing to use jquery+ajax to connect to existent data tier. So basically I just need a jquery plugin to handle presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into jquery datatables http://datatables.net/

As well as jqGrid http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx

These are the 2 big jquery table plugins which interact with serverside processing to do CRUD operations.

datatables has better customizations as far as clientside bells and whistles where as jqgrid is a little harder to make look as pretty but can do some pretty good serverside interaction from what I understand.

Comment: I would actually use rather small amount of data. How about something like this comment section under each answer. Basically it is a similar control that allows editing, deleting and inserting new comments, just optimized with jquery.